# Regular expressions: remove non alpha numerics, with an exception

Tags: regex, postgresql

To remove all non-alpha numeric chars, the regex would be

```
x = regexp_replace(somestring, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '', 'g')
```

But what if I want to leave underscores untouched ?

Comment: `a-zA-Z0-9_` is equivalent to `\w`. It's easier to read like that.

Comment: Additionally, `[^\w]+` is equivalent to `\W+`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Then you need to use :

```
x = regexp_replace(somestring, '\W+', '', 'g')
```

`\W` is the same as `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Answer (score 2):

How about using '\W+' that replaces all non a-z and 0-9 leaving _ alone

So

```
x = regexp_replace(somestring, '\W+', '', 'g')
```